# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.3, profile.blade.php.

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to show the users profile information who are logged in,I have two tables one is Message and other one is User, when user login it see his\her profile, but there is an error.

profile.blade:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $usr)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$usr->name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$usr->email}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
public function GetUserInfo($id){
    $user = DB::table('users')
        ->join('messages', 'messages.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
    if($user->count()){
        $user = $user->first();
        return view('profile')->with('users',$user);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    class Messages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $fillable = [
        'message','user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$users` in your blade file be `$user` in head of the `@foreach` loop?

Comment: your codes and problem statement doesn't convey your requirment!! can you explain bit more what you wan to do with it!!! So that i can suggest you a better way to do it.

Comment: primary key of User ( id ) is foreign key in Message( user_id ) and there is one controller of Message i get the users information form User table through relation and join.

Answer (score 1):

When passing data to views this way, `users` should be an array.

Change your controller like this:

```
public function GetUserInfo($id){
    $user = DB::table('users')
        ->join('messages', 'messages.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $id)
        ->get()->toArray();
    if($user->count()){
        $user = $user->first();
        return view('profile')->with('users',$user);
    }
}
```

And your profile blade view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $usr)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$usr['name']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$usr['email']}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
    if($user->count()){
        $user = $user->first();
        return view('profile')->with('users',$user);
    }
```

`first()` is called on queries, but `$user` already exists as a Laravel collection by the time it enters the if statement. It should exist as an object or an array, and you can access it as such. Something like

```
if($user->count()){
        $user = $user[0]; /*OR*/
        $user = $user->0; 
        return view('profile')->with('users',$user);
}
```

I don't recall which is the right way off the top of my head. `print_r($user)` before to see what it looks like.